# List#map in Parallel with `par`

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

Given:

```
scala> def f(x: Int): Future[Int] = 
             Future.successful { Thread.sleep(5000); println(x); x }
f: (x: Int)scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
```

The following call takes roughly 15 seconds to run (5 seconds per `f`'s application to each element).

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(f)
1
2
3
res67: List[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]] = List(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise
         $KeptPromise@6a2e699e, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@1f6c8d1f, 
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@5c8d17d1)
```

I can use `par` to, as I incompletely understand, parallelize it.

If I use it, then the execution time shrinks to roughly 5 seconds.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).par.map(f).toList
2
3
1
res68: List[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]] = 
    List(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@7838df8, 
           scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@4b1b7563, 
                 scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@721165a0)
```

Is this parallelization the recommended way in Scala? What are alternatives?

Comment: Why the down votes? I can't recall the video,  but I recall hearing doubts about the robustness of this par library.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

`Future.successful` creates an already completed future and to do it it must evaluate its argument. What you want is slightly different and consists in running each future and then wait for completion of each one

```
def f(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println(x); x }
```

And then

```
List(1,2,3).map(f).map(f => Await.result(f,Duration(5, SECONDS)))
```